# Cosine similarity between rows of two large dataframes in R

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance, cosine-similarity, stringdist

I've two dataframes DF1 and DF2. One of them is a very large DF.

I've created examples DF1 and 2 like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

A<-rep(c('Mavs', 'Spurs', 'Lakers', 'Cavs', 'Suns'), 1000000)
DF1<-data.frame(A)

B<-rep(c('Rockets', 'Pacers', 'Warriors', 'Suns', 'Celtics'), 1000)
DF2<-data.frame(B)
```

I want to compute cosine similarity and levenshtein distance of each word in DF1 to each word of DF2 and store it in a DataFrame. To do that in a "tidy way", I used the package "fuzzyjoin". I'm trying something like this:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
DF1 <- DF1 %>% stringdist_full_join (DF2, by = c('A' = 'B'), 
                              method = "cosine", 
                              distance_col = "distance Cos")
```

This works fine with small datasets. But the problem is the large amount of data of DF1 and DF2. R gives me the message of Error: cannot allocate vector of size N Gb.

Is there a simple way to solve this problem? Is possible to calculate the levenshtein distance too?

I will appreciate help! Thanks!

Comment: That is abillion checks. Unless you are using a super computer, that wont work. Consider changing from R to any compiled languages ie C++, Fortran, C, julia(maybe) etc... No way to compute abillion string manipulations in R. Or you could also compute the similarity between the uniques, then join the uniques and join the fulls on the uniques

Comment: Another idea is to break down the code such that you do batch checks, and store them in a file. Continue appending to the file

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you recomendation. I've reduced the number of comparations adding the attribute "max_dist":
DF1 <- DF1 %>% stringdist_full_join (DF2, by = c('A' = 'B'), 
                              method = "cosine", 
                              distance_col = "distance Cos",
                              max_dist = 0.020)
I saved records in a file every 100.000 comparations.